# Error when storing JSON data in variable

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am new to `json` and `d3`, it may be a rookie mistake.
I am trying to store json data in variable but its giving unexpected token u error.

here is my code where I am parsing and storing the data -

```
var links = [];
var nodes = [];
var data;

d3.json("sample1.json", function(error, data) {

  nodes = JSON.parse(data).nodes;
  links = JSON.parse(data).links;   
});
```

json file is like this -

```
{
 "nodes":[
          {""name"":""17925"",""group"":6}, 
          {""name"":""20209"",""group"":215}]
  "links"[
          {""source"":0,""target"":98,""value"":1},   
          {""source"":0,""target"":108,""value"":2}]
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the JSON is really the way you show it here, check the script that generates it, the double quotes are really wrong

Comment: Corrected the script that was generating the JSON. Now JSON is fine. 
Now I am getting unexpected token o error.

Comment: @SoniShashank: That's because the JSON is parsed twice. The second time it will turn the object into the string `"[object Object]"` and try to parse that as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`d3.json` method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json) already parses the JSON for you:

> "the callback is invoked with two arguments: the error, if any, and
>   the parsed JSON."

So, you don't have to parse it again:

```
var links, nodes;

d3.json("sample1.json", function(error, data) {
    nodes = data.nodes;
    links = data.links;
});
```

As roryok pointed out, the JSON has double qoutation marks. Also, it is missing the object specifier around the properties, it should be:

```
{
  "nodes":[{"name":"17925","group":6},{"name":"20209","group":215}]
  "links"[{"source":0,"target":98,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":108,"value":2}]
}
```

Side note: The method is asynchronous, so the callback function will be called later, when the data arrives. You have declared the variables outside the call, but they won't contain the data immediately after the call.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are double quoting the values in nodes and links. Try this instead

```
"nodes":[{"name":"17925","group":6},{"name":"20209","group":215}]
"links"[{"source":0,"target":98,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":108,"value":2}]
```

Comment: Corrected the script that was generating the JSON. Now JSON is fine. Now I am getting unexpected token o error.

Comment: I'd guess maybe you hit o instead of 0 somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON files are not valid thats why JSON.parse won't work.

A valid JSON file would be this (1 and 2 are IDs in this case).

```
{
   "nodes":{
      "1":{
         "name":"17925",
         "group":6
      },
      "2":{
         "name":"20209",
         "group":215
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Double quotes inside string values should be escaped; According to [the specs](https://es5.github.io/x15.12.html), `"` is a `JSONEscapeCharacter`:

> JSONEscapeCharacter :: one of
>   `" / \ b f n r t`

Also, it seems you're missing a colon (`:`) after the `links` property key.

This will pass parsing:

```json
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "\"name\"": "\"17925\"",
            "\"group\"": 6
        },
        {
            "\"name\"": "\"20209\"",
            "\"group\"": 215
        }
    ],    
    "links": [
        {
            "\"source\"": 0,
            "\"target\"": 98,
            "\"value\"": 1
        },
        {
            "\"source\"": 0,
            "\"target\"": 108,
            "\"value\"": 2
        }
    ]
}
```